# How do I get all the tags that are assigned to a file in git?

Tags: git

I need to to tell which revision/SHA1 of a file was associated with one or more tags.  In CVS it is possible to get an output similar to to this:

> **File**: abc.txt 
>   *Rev*: 1.0 
>   *Tags*: R1_0, R1_1
>
> *Rev*: 1.1 
>   *Tags*: R1_2

How do you get a **tag history for a file** with git?

Edit:
I frequently use this function to tell which **revision** of a file is in production.  I know which version (tag) of software is in production.  Based upon this I would like to know which revision of a given file was tagged (and also which previous tags were associated to this file revision).

In my example above:
 R1_1 will be in production.  Querying abc.txt, I can tell that rev1.0 for abc.txt was used for both R1_0 and R1_1.  (Thus unlikely that a **new** bug in R1_1 was caused by abc.txt because it still the same file as R1_0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're trying to be too specific in literally translating concepts from one revision control system to another.  I'd ask, "how has `abc.txt` changed since `R1_1`?"

```
git log R1_1.. -- abc.txt
```

Now you know two things -- that it's changed, and how.  Toss in a `-p` if you want to see the changes, too.

### Less Helpful, but What You Asked For:

To do exactly what you're asking for (which I think is less useful), and assuming you're [tagging properly](http://www.rockstarprogrammer.org/post/2008/oct/16/git-tag-does-wrong-thing-default/):

```
git describe `git log --pretty=format:%H -n 1 abc.txt`
```

That shows you closest thing to a tag name for the last commit that changed the file.

Answer (score 1):

In git tags are always associated with state of **whole project**, not with the version of a single **file**. You can easily get however list of all files that changed between versions with "`git diff --name-only R1_0 R1_1`" (or more descriptive "`git diff --stat --summary R1_0 R1_1`". You can get last commit that touched a file with "`git log -1 <file>`".

But if you want to find a bug, it is much better in my opinion to use [**git-bisect**](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bisect.html) command to find which revision introduced bug. You would know not only which file has a bug, but which part of file introduced it (what change creared it).

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to accomplish? The SHA1 identifies the state of the entire repo at that point in time.

Comment: Updated my question to describe my intent better.